# Running FEniCS with in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fenics

I've installed FEniCS for Anaconda using `conda-forge` as explained on [this](https://fenicsproject.org/download/) page using the following command:

```
conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge fenics
```

I then activate it:

```
source activate fenicsproject
```

If I then run python directly and `import fenics` then everything works fine, however if I run a `juptyter notebook` then the import fails.

I can also see that the `which python` is different in the console than it is in the notebook.
Console:

```
/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/bin/python
```

Notebook:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Do I need to install a new kernel? If so, how do I find the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to follow the instructions of this link?
https://fenicsproject.org/qa/13194/how-to-use-fenics-in-jupyter-by-anaconda/

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .bashrc file

export PYTHONPATH=~/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/lib/python3.7/site-packages